# Book involving clones, "The System", “Mama Mercury “, and an abandoned monastery on the Moon?

Tags: story-identification, books

I’ve been searching for this book for a while, to no avail. I read it as a teen somewhere between 2005 and 2013, in the UK. From what I can remember, it was a *Star Wars* style “ragtag gang of rogues/rebels fighting the imperial system”. I seem to remember there was a focus on the use of clones as well. Some other details:

- Most planets in the solar system were colonised
- There was an abandoned monastery on the Moon
- The imperial government was called something like “the system”
- One of the antagonists was called “mama Mercury" or "mother mercy", or something similar
- The ending had a twist involving the main character’s clone as a prisoner, unfortunately I can’t remember it properly!
- "the system" (imperial government) had more than 26 letters in their official alphabet
- at one point, one of the characters enters into some sort of space gladiator contest and fairly savagely murders someone to win

The only slightly similar novel I have found was 2312, but despite the similarities I don't think that was it.

Any clues or ideas of the book name would be much appreciated; I’ve honestly no idea what the title was, despite googling all of the above loads!

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26127606-creation-machine + https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54303716-rich-man-s-sky - Monasteries on the moon are a pretty common trope

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any details of the cover (colour, images)?  Any idea when it was set, or bits of the technology that stuck in your memory?

Comment: Sadly nothing of any great detail. I do remember they used some sort of "fast travel" and one scene mentioned how they moved away from solar as it wasn't taxable. I do also remember some sort of imperial guard militia type role, but can't remember specific details.

Comment: What does "pin abandoned" mean?

Comment: "Most planets in the solar system were colonised" -- should I take this to mean that most or all of the plot took place within our own solar system? As in, the human race had not yet developed any FTL travel which would allow people to visit other solar systems after a *very fast* trip? If so, that would eliminate a few things which had popped into my head as I first read your description of the loose parallels with Star Wars.

Comment: @lorendiac - yeah I seem to remember it was in this solar system, but characters could fairly easily travel planet to planet without it taking up much plot time.

Comment: @fuzzyboots, apologies it's a typo, have corrected

Comment: This sounds very like something from John Varley's "Eight Worlds" series.